# MySQL select - Adding duplicite rows data to new columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have this two tables in MySQL (MariaDB):

Table DATA

```
+------+------+
|id    |object|
+------+------+
|1     |AFD   |
+------+------+
|2     |AFG   |
+------+------+
|3     |ASD   |
+------+------+
|4     |BDS   |
+------+------+
|5     |BDF   |
+------+------+
```

Table WORK

```
+------+------+
|id    |action|
+------+------+
|1     |34    |
+------+------+
|1     |54    |
+------+------+
|1     |65    |
+------+------+
|2     |73    |
+------+------+
|2     |11    |
+------+------+
```

To every id in table DATA there are several id's in table WORK.
I need to get the output like this:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|id    |object|action1|action2|action3|
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|1     |AFD   |34     |54     |64     |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|2     |AFG   |73     |11     |NULL   |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are looking on how to build a pivot table

Comment: I didn't know about pivot table, now I can google it. Thanks. Maybe one question. Is this effective on tables with 100k+ rows?